# how to add some textbox with Code

Tags: vb.net

i have trouble with this
[Click Here for picture](http://prntscr.com/56a4u8)
The Code

```
Dim Tex1 As TextBox = Nothing  
Dim Tex2 As TextBox = Nothing
Tex1 = New Windows.Forms.TextBox
Tex1.Name = "TextBox"
Tex1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 119)
Tex1.Size = TextBox1.Size
Tex1.TabIndex = 4
Tex2 = New Windows.Forms.TextBox
Tex2.Name = "TextBox"
Tex2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(110, 119)
Tex2.Size = TextBox2.Size
Tex2.TabIndex = 5
Me.Controls.Add(Tex1)
Me.Controls.Add(Tex2)
```

i want to add the new textbox with clicking the picture box, like this
[Click Here for Picture](http://prntscr.com/56a4it)
but when i click the "add Picture Box" the textbox not appear
please, anyone help me ?

Comment: since the problem at least starts with the picturebox click event, please show *that* code

Comment: Increment your location X and Y coordinates otherwise you will be adding the new one on top of the old one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have the ability to add textboxes to your form then this is what you should do. First you will need to identify the button that you are going to use for this insertion event. I would assume the green plus symbol.

Then I would create a mouse event action like this:

```
Public Sub Mouse_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyButton.Click
    ' Some action...
End Sub
```

From there you will be able to insert your code into the click event like this:

```
Public Sub Mouse_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyButton.Click
    Dim Tex1 As TextBox = Nothing  
    Dim Tex2 As TextBox = Nothing
    Tex1 = New Windows.Forms.TextBox
    Tex1.Name = "TextBox"
    Tex1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 119)
    Tex1.Size = TextBox1.Size
    Tex1.TabIndex = 4
    Tex2 = New Windows.Forms.TextBox
    Tex2.Name = "TextBox"
    Tex2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(110, 119)
    Tex2.Size = TextBox2.Size
    Tex2.TabIndex = 5
    Me.Controls.Add(Tex1)
    Me.Controls.Add(Tex2)
End Sub
```

Now there is still a big issue with this code, the location of the textboxes. The reason this is an issue is because they are static, meaning they will always appear in the same spot so, one solution is to declare a global `Point()` to maintain the location of the newest textbox like this:

```
Dim tbLocation1 As Point = New Point(12, 199)
Dim tbLocation2 As Point = New Point(110, 199)
```

From there all you would then need to do is have some sort of margin amount that you want to move the textboxes by like this:

```
Dim marginAmt As Int32 = 30
```

Now that all of the pieces are present lets put it together:

```
Dim tbLocation1 As Point = New Point(12, 199)
Dim tbLocation2 As Point = New Point(110, 199)
Dim marginAmt As Int32 = 30

Public Sub Mouse_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyButton.Click
    Dim Tex1 As TextBox = New Windows.Forms.TextBox 
    Dim Tex2 As TextBox = New Windows.Forms.TextBox

    ' Modifies Tex1
    Tex1.Name = "TextBox"
    Tex1.Location = tbLocation1
    Tex1.Size = TextBox1.Size
    Tex1.TabIndex = 4

    ' Modifies Tex2
    Tex2.Name = "TextBox"
    Tex2.Location = tbLocation2
    Tex2.Size = TextBox2.Size
    Tex2.TabIndex = 5

    ' Updates form
    Me.Controls.Add(Tex1)
    Me.Controls.Add(Tex2)

    ' Updates the point locations
    tbLocation1 = New Point(tbLocation1.X, tbLocation1.Y + marginAmt)
    tbLocation2 = New Point(tbLocation2.X, tbLocation2.Y + marginAmt)

End Sub
```

Now you just need to connect this event action to the button that you desire.